# using other than

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> Finding it so directly on the threshold of our narrative, which is now about to issue from that inauspicious portal, **we could hardly do otherwise than** pluck one of its flowers and present it to the reader.

Would you tell me if I can properly rephrase the bold part as:

> **we could hardly do anything other than**

Any help would be appreciated

<sub>From the book: *The Scarlet Letter*</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I think you've rephrased it quite well.

Hawthorne's work, having been written in 1850, probably contains a lot of languauge we're unlikely to hear in modern conversation. For example, when I Googled:

`"on the threshold of our narrative,"`

unsuprisingly, I found thousands of results (most of them either copies of *The Scarlet Letter*, or else commentary on it). But when I changed the Google query to:

`"threshold of our narrative" -portal -directly`

I could only find that *"threshold of our narrative"* phrase in just three other places that weren't quoting or commenting on Hawthorne. (One was a 1905 biography of Johannes Brahms, another was an 1864 article published in the Scottish periodical *The North British Review*, and the third an 1894 non-fiction work about the Jesuits in China.)

I realize you weren't asking about "threshold of our narrative," but I didn't want any learners being alarmed if they found the rest of the quote as puzzling as the part you asked about. It's not easy English, even for native speakers.